# Issues with using AWS DynamoDB CRUD functions in Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-dynamodb, crud

I'm facing issues with creating a CRUD API for DynamoDB. I keep getting 500 code errors for deletion and update operations. I'm not facing any issues with GET requests though (which uses query). My code is as follows:-

PATCH (for update operation)

```
    elif request.method == 'PATCH':
        data = request.get_json()
        key = {
               'id': data['id'],
               'timestamp': data['timestamp']
        }
        try:
            response = table.update_item(
                Key = key,
                UpdateExpression = "SET title=:t, blurb=:b, category=:c, img=:i",
                ExpressionAttributeValues = {
                    ':t': data['title'],
                    ':b': data['blurb'],
                    ':c': data['category'],
                    ':i': data['img']
                }, # TYPE BOOK CONTAINS OTHER FIELDS ALSO
                ReturnValues = "UPDATED_NEW"
            )
            return jsonify(response)
        except ClientError as e:
            print("ITEM NOT UPDATED")
```

I'm defining both keys in the key condition because my primary key contains both values. Similarly, the code for DELETE is as follows:

```
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        key = {
            'id': data['id'],
            'timestamp': data['timestamp']
        }
        try:
            response = table.delete_item(
                Key = key,
                ReturnValues = "DELETED"
            )
            return jsonify(response)
        except ClientError as e:
            print("ITEM NOT DELETED")
            return jsonify("ITEM NOT DELETED")
```

The output I get is as follows (in my app for print(request.body)):

```
I/flutter (21896): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
I/flutter (21896): <title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
I/flutter (21896): <h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
I/flutter (21896): <p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
```

Any help to solve this issue would be readily appreciated. I tried searching for a clue, but nothing shown online seems to work. The flask seems to work as intended without the DynamoDB commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was here:

```
            response = table.delete_item(
                Key = key,
                ReturnValues = "DELETED"
            )
```

ReturnValues should be omitted in the case of Delete operations. Also DELETED is not an allowed keyword for ReturnValues expression in DynamoDB.